# How can I prove that this function doesn't have a second weak derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, weak-derivatives

I'm trying to determine what weak derivatives the function 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x&\mbox{if }0<x<1,\\
1&\mbox{if }1\leq x<2,
\end{cases}
$$
has.

I already managed to prove that it has a first weak deriviative
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\mbox{if }0<x<1,\\
0&\mbox{if }1\leq x<2.
\end{cases}
$$
I'm pretty confident that this deriviative does not have a weak deriviate of its own.
How could I prove it?

So far I came to realise that if $h$ was a weak deriviative of $g$, it would need to fulfill the following equation:

$$\int h\cdot \psi = -\psi(1)$$
for every $\psi$ which is a function in $L^1_\mbox{loc}$. I got it by integration by parts, and using the fact that $\psi$ would need to be zero on $0$ and $2$.

Is it the right way to go? I could not find a combination of $\psi$'s that would lead me towards a contradiction.

Comment: The derivative is $f'=1$ on $(0,1)$, $f'=0$ on $(1,2)$. The  2nd order (distributional) derivative is the (minus) Dirac in $1$ (i.e. $-\delta_1$).

Comment: Also, note that the Dirac delta distribution is not a function!

Comment: @Milly
 How can I show that the 2nd order deriviative is dirac's function? how can I show that there isn't a function that would be the deriviative?

Comment: You actually proved that when you wrote $\int h\psi=-\psi(1)$, which gives $h=-\delta_1$ by definition of Dirac delta. Since that is also a necessary condition, only the $-\delta_1$ would be acceptable as 2nd derivative, and since $-\delta_1$ is not a function (e.g. by noting that its integral on a singleton $\{1\}$ is nonzero in general), you conclude that $f''$ cannot coincide with any function.

Comment: @Milly
I disagree. The condition for a function h to be delta is that for every function psi we'd get:
integral (h*psi)=psi(0).
But in this case i assumed that it is right only for phi's which are in L1_loc.

Comment: @RonMor What you described is the Delta in $0$. Delta in $1$ means $\int \delta_{1}\phi=\phi(1)$, for any test $\phi\in C_c^\infty$. Since you proved for any $\phi\in L^1_{loc}$ it holds $\int h\phi=-\phi(1)$, and $L^1_{loc}\supset C_c^\infty$, you conclude that $h$ is $-\delta_1$.

Comment: @Milly
Please excuse me for my ignorance.
I understand intuitivly why the property I proved means that h is dira'c delta, but I never actually had a formal definition of it.
For all I know, this equality needs to hold for every integrable or maybe continious function psi, not only for smooth functions. Is this where I don't understand correctly?
I tried to google a proper definition of dirac's delta but no site offered me one.

Comment: The Dirac $\delta$ is defined on a space of tests, which is generally assumed $C_c^\infty$ (or Schwarz space).  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html and http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Delta-function have some description on the test space.